# Processing GET Body with Zuul

Tags: servlets, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using Zuul to proxy a strange client that sends a body as part of a GET request. There is unfortunately no way I can change the client.

With curl such a request can be sent as:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:8765/kibana/index.html' -d' {"key": "value"}'
```

And the data is really sent in the body. On zuul side, however, when I try to read the body it is empty. Here is my prototype zuul code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulServerApplication {

    @Bean
    public ZuulFilter myFilter() {
    return new ZuulFilter(){

        @Override
        public Object run() {
            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
            HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)ctx.getRequest();
            try {
                InputStream is=request.getInputStream();
                String content=IOUtils.toString(is);
                System.out.println("Request content:"+content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldFilter() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int filterOrder() {
            return 10;
        }
        @Override
        public String filterType() {
            return "pre";
        }};
    }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulServerApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
        }

    }
```

If I send a POST request, the this code prints the request body without problem. However, if I send the above GET request, the body is not printed. Anything I can do to actually get the body sent as part of a GET request?

Comment: It seems that some underlying machinery does not proxy input stream when it is `GET` method with body. Since when `filterOder` is `10`, `HttpServletRequestWrapper` will be returned from `ctx.getRequest()` which is normally able to handle multiple acquisition of input stream.

If `filterOrder` is changed to e.g. `-10` then it works for this filter since more raw `HttpServletRequest` is used (no other filter could replace `HttpServletRequest` with `HttpServletRequestWrapper`). But it might exhaust input stream for something else.

Comment: That's a good for me. I tested and it works. Would you mind posting as an answer?

Comment: That's good. I did with some elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some underlying machinery[0], e.g. some built-in Zuul filter with lesser filter order, replaces default "raw" `HttpServletRequest` with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which, under standard circumstances (i.e. not `GET` method with body), is able to handle multiple acquisition of input stream. But in the case of `GET` method with body `HttpServletRequestWrapper` seems to *not* proxy input stream at all.

**Thus solution could be to change `filterOrder` e.g. to `-10`.**

Then it works for the filter since `HttpServletRequest` is used - the mentioned machinery did not get to its turn and thus didn't replace `HttpServletRequest` with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` yet. But potential issue with this solution is that the filter might exhaust input stream for something else, e.g. filter with higher filter order. But since `GET` with body is not a good practice anyway, it might be good enough solution after all :)

[0] I've debug into this longer time ago, but did not get to exact point - thus vague definition of "the machinery".